# How many gold coins do I need to unlock all powers on all skylanders?

Tags: skylanders

I find it exciting getting new powers to beat Kaos with. How rich do I need to be to get all the powers in the game?

Answer (score 3):

According to [this page](http://www.darkspyro.net/skylanders/upgrades/), which also lists all of the upgrades for a number of the Skylanders, you will need 11,360 coins if you have the 20% discount you get for collecting all ten Winged Sapphires, otherwise you will need 14,200 coins to fully upgrade **each** Skylander you have.

Since there are 32 Skylanders, you will need 363,520 coins total with the discount, and 454,400 if you do not have the 20% discount.

The linked page also mentions the following note:

> Note that you can't buy an upgrade that enhances another ability if
>   you haven't already bought that ability to enhance. For example you
>   cannot buy Spyro's Soul Gem ability "Spyro's Earth Pound" before you
>   have purchased the "Spyro's Flight" power even though it appears on
>   the upgrade screen.